# -bash: raspistill: command not found

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, video-streaming, raspberry-pi-zero, raspberry-pi-os

I am trying to hook up my Raspberry Pi Zero W, running Raspberry Pi OS Lite, to a Raspberry Pi NoIR Camera Module V2.  After running these commands:

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

and enabling the camera in the `raspi-config` menu and rebooting per the Raspberry Pi documentation, when I run the command `raspistill -v -o test.jpg` according to the Raspbery {Pi documentation, I get the below error.

```sh
-bash: raspistill: command not found
```

The documentation says:

> This probably means your update/upgrade failed in some way.

I tried it again. I ran update, upgrade commands, rebooted and enabled the camera in the raspi-config multiple times with no change in outcome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

raspistill has been replaced by libcamera.

https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/accessories/camera.html#libcamera-and-libcamera-apps

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me hell lot of time.